# Django ORM `queryset.distinct()` gets duplicate values due to `.ordered_by()` on the column

Tags: python, sql, django-orm

To make the long story short, we have a QuerySet of transactions of the same `product_id`, ordered by the primary key `id`.

However, when retrieving the distinct `product_id`, the query set returns duplications. It seems that the `.ordered_by(id)` forced the query set to include column `id`, so the distinct query got the same `product_id` with different `id`'s.

The Python program appended the `.ordered_by()` clause to the query set, and then passed it as an argument to a function call. And we are trying to get the distinct value in the function.

We wonder how to get the expected distinct value.

**Sample source code to illustrate the issue:**

```py
qs_transactions = Transaction.active_objects.filter(product_id=fixed_value).order_by('id')
...

def function(qs_transactions)
  qs_product_id = qs_transactions.values('product_id').distinct()
  ...
```

**The SQL generated by Django, with pretty formatting:**

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    `app_transaction`.`product_id`
  , `app_transaction`.`id` 
FROM `app_transaction` 
WHERE 
  ... conditions ...
ORDER BY `app_transaction`.`id` ASC
```